# How to save images in ascending order in swift?

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I am building an application in which i am using FileManager to save some images using device camera. So for Now I am saving file name as Doc-Time.
I am using below code,

```
func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage ) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    
    let fileName = "Doc-" + dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName
    )
    if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0),!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("file saved")
        } catch {
            print("error saving file:", error)
        }
    }
}
```

But Here i want to as, Doc-1,Doc-2, Doc-3....
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply storing the next index of the image. Like first the index should be 1 when you used named the image as Doc-1 then the index has 2 in it and so on....

One way to store this index in UserDefaults like:

```
var nextImageIndex: Int {
    UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "NextImageIndex") + 1  //+1 if you want to start with 1
}
    
func incrementImageIndex() {
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nextImageIndex, forKey: "NextImageIndex")
}
```

Put the above code somewhere in UIViewController to see it works.

Here is your updated method...

```
func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage ) {
    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return
    }
    
    let fileName = "Doc-\(nextImageIndex)"
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let fileAlreadyExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path)
    if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0), !fileAlreadyExists {
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            incrementImageIndex()
            print("file saved")
        } catch {
            print("error saving file:", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.
I couldn't understand it can you give explain it using my function?

Comment: Ok let me update my answer using your function.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer it is working fine, but when i am starting from 1 it is saving as Doc-1, Doc-3,Doc-5,Doc-7

Comment: No it will save images as Doc-1, Doc-2, Doc-3 so on

Comment: Try to print the filename

Comment: And Also after 3-4 Docs it is not saving more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235952/discussion-between-najeeb-ur-rehman-and-abhishek-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to store the document count and increment it every time your save to the document directory, then use that value in the string.

```
let documentKey = "documentIndex" 

@objc var documentIndex: Int {
    get { UserDefaults.value(forKey: documentKey) as? Int ?? 0 }
    set { UserDefaults.setValue(newValue, forKey: documentKey) }
}

func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage ) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    documentIndex += 1
    
    let fileName = "Doc-\(documentIndex)"
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName
    )
    if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0),!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("file saved")
        } catch {
            print("error saving file:", error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will just work for single app session and repeats in the next session.

Comment: Hi clawesome, it is working fine untill app is running for the first time, but when app is restarting it is not working properly, i mean when i first launched app and saved 2 files, it worked, then i restarted my app, in that case , i had to click three times to get Doc-3

Comment: You didn't specify needing to persist the value between sessions.  I can adjust the code to address that, but in the future you should try to be more specific in all of your requirements.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I updated the code so the value persists between sessions.

Comment: Thanks clawesome, i will be more specific in my requirement. :)